# Why is Aegisub no longer available in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, subtitle

I recently updated to Bionic Beaver but Aegisub is no longer available in Ubuntu repositories.

I don't know of any other alternative and it's not the first time I've lost a program when upgrading :(

Does anyone know:

1. Why it was removed from Ubuntu repositories?
2. Any alternative I could use without add a third party repo?

Thanks~

Comment: I just tried Gaupol and I can probably use it although I'd still like to know what happened to Aegisub.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could find no hints as to why Aegisub has vanished although I believe that it was dropped from Debian Buster (which Bionic Beaver is based upon).

**Update**: [fkraiem](https://askubuntu.com/users/256317/fkraiem) has found [the relevant Debian entry](https://tracker.debian.org/news/874946/aegisub-removed-from-testing/) and [the relevant bugreport](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=873327).

Notwithstanding Debian's issues on 'Buster' I have managed to compile my own copy of Aegisub on Bionic Beaver. This is good solid option for you to regain access to this application *without* using a 3rd party repository.

As it is an older application some massaging of the source with sed has been required, otherwise there are really only *2 simple steps* to take:

**1. Dependencies and build tools:**

Copy and paste this *entire* code block into a Terminal window to download and install some required dependencies and build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libx11-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev \
libfreetype6-dev pkg-config libfontconfig1-dev libass-dev libboost1.62-all-dev \
liblua50-dev libasound2-dev libffms2-dev intltool
```

**2. Download, compile and install the source:**

Copy and paste the following lines into a Terminal window to download, extract, modify, compile and install the Aegisub source:

```
mkdir -v $HOME/aegisub_build && cd $HOME/aegisub_build
wget http://ftp.aegisub.org/pub/archives/releases/source/aegisub-3.2.2.tar.xz
tar xvf aegisub-3.2.2.tar.xz && cd aegisub-3.2.2
sed -i 's/$(LIBS_BOOST) $(LIBS_ICU)/$(LIBS_BOOST) $(LIBS_ICU) -pthread/' tools/Makefile
sed -i '46 a\#include <unicode/unistr.h>' src/utils.cpp
CPPFLAGS="-DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=1" ./configure && make -j 2
sudo checkinstall -D --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir "$HOME/aegisub_build" \
   --pkgname aegisub --backup=no --deldoc=yes --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default \
   --pkgversion "3.2.2"
```

The sed magic has been drawn from many sources, looks like Arch and Slackware are both keeping the application alive :).

**3. Screenshot:**

And a final screenshot demonstrating Aegisub successfully running on my Bionic system:

[image]

Comment: `aegisub` was [removed from Debian testing in September](https://tracker.debian.org/news/874946/aegisub-removed-from-testing/) due to [this FTBFS](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=873327).

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks for finding that! Looks like it builds from source here OK although I have not tested the application extensively. I am waiting for the OP to say if he or she is happy with the build. Perhaps this patch needs including but I will hold off for the moment...

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. Also, I hadn't considered the possibility of compiling it myself. it worked like a charm and it even created a debian package for it.

Comment: @Meh Great to hear that this has worked out! Checkinstall does not create a fully portable debian package but it certainly integrates the package into the Ubuntu package management system.

Comment: I comment to ask for the pull request that fixes the issue to be merged (https://github.com/Aegisub/Aegisub/pull/48) and it's now merged, hopefully it won't be too long to make the package available again :-)

Comment: I created a Docker image (for my own use) to be able to run Aegisub from any OS, maybe it will be useful to other people :-) https://github.com/bperel/aegisub-docker

Comment: @BrunoPérel why is the xhost + needed? how can it be reverted?

Comment: @Fuseteam The xhost + is needed to share the X environment between the host and the Docker container

Comment: would it be better to share the X enviroment with the specific container?

Comment: i would like to snap the application to keep it installable and working, but i'll need some help setting up what it needs to install/build properly. [github repo here](https://github.com/Fuseteam/aegisub-snap)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your proposed solution is using the vendor source luajit provided by the aegisub source dating back to ~ 2014.
In Debian and Ubuntu we instead build the package aegisub using the system installed libraries, which are regularly upgraded by the developers. This means that from now on, we use luajit version 2.1.0 instead of version 2.0.x. The usual procedure is for the developers of an application using these libraries to update their code. However, aegisub isn't anymore supported by its developers...

And compared to the previous 2.0.x version of the luajit library, it looks like there is some differences for the C code interpretation.
The blocking error comes from file vendor/luabins/src/luabins.c

```
/* luabins Lua module API */
static const struct luaL_reg R[] =
{
  { "save", l_save },
  { "load", l_load },
  { NULL, NULL }
};
```

giving the above mentioned error:

```
aegisub/aegisub-3.2.2/vendor/luabins/src/luabins.c:57:30: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘struct luaL_reg’
 static const struct luaL_reg R[] =
                              ^
/home/ubuntu-xenial/pascal/Downloads/Launchpad/aegisub/aegisub-3.2.2/vendor/luabins/src/luabins.c:57:30: warning: ‘R’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
Makefile.target:99: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu-xenial/pascal/Downloads/Launchpad/aegisub/aegisub-3.2.2/vendor/luabins/src/luabins.o' failed
```

Even building against lua5.2 instead of lua5.1, the error is still there.

Hence, since the debian package manager cannot contact any aegisub developer to ask for an update, this app was removed from the Debian repository.

For further reference have a look at:

[Lua 5.2 compatibility](https://github.com/clementfarabet/lua---camera/issues/23)
[Array element has incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458042/array-element-has-incomplete-type)